# What are the differences between Model, ModelMap, and ModelAndView?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

What are the main differences between the following [Spring Framework](http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/) classes?

- `Model`
- `ModelMap`
- `ModelAndView`

Using `Model.put(String,Object)` we can access the values in `.jsp` files, but `ModelMap.addAttribute(String,Object)` also did same thing. I do not understand the difference between these classes.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

`Model` is an interface while `ModelMap` is a class.

`ModelAndView` is just a container for both a `ModelMap` and a view object. It allows a controller to return both as a single value.

Comment: After digging around, the best reason that I found to use a ModelMap (kind of buried in vikas harle's answer and not shown in example) is that when adding attributes to a ModelMap, you can leave out the attribute name (key) and spring will generate the attribute key based on the attribute value.
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.14.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-coc-modelmap

Comment: So, then what's the point and different when returning ModelAndView? in the case of returning String and letting ViewResolver to fetch respective view page, you still return only one type - and it's string (view name), model is being implicitly taken cared by DispatcherServlet.. what's the use-case distinction?

Answer (score 36):

**Differences between Model, ModelMap, and ModelAndView**

**Model:** It is an Interface. It defines a holder for model attributes and primarily designed for adding attributes to the model.

Example:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printHello(Model model) {
          model.addAttribute("message", "Hello World!!");
          return "hello";
       }
```

**ModelMap:** Implementation of Map for use when building model data for    use with UI tools.Supports chained calls and    generation of model attribute names.

Example:

```
@RequestMapping("/helloworld")
public String hello(ModelMap map) {
    String helloWorldMessage = "Hello world!";
    String welcomeMessage = "Welcome!";
    map.addAttribute("helloMessage", helloWorldMessage);
    map.addAttribute("welcomeMessage", welcomeMessage);
    return "hello";
}
```

**ModelAndView:** This class merely holds both to make it possible for a controller to return both model and view in a single return value.

Example:

```
@RequestMapping("/welcome")
public ModelAndView helloWorld() {
        String message = "Hello World!";
        return new ModelAndView("welcome", "message", message);
    }
```

Comment: Should we add Model or ModelMap in the method parameters to access it in the view.

Comment: Your second example doesn't show the difference between `Model` and `ModelMap`... both examples are the same.

Comment: Model also support chained calls.  Model is an interface, whereas ModelMap is an implementation of Map interface. Hence the latter have method such as forEach, which the former don't have

Answer (score 14):

**Model**: is an interface it contains four addAttribute and one merAttribute method.

**ModelMap**: implements Map interface. It also contains Map method.

**ModelAndView**: As Bart explain it allows a controller return both as a single value.

Comment: Is "merAttribute" actually referring to "mergeAttributes"?  Also, there are not "four addAttribute" methods.  Rather, there are four methods for adding attributes, at least as far as version 5.0.4 of the Spring framework is concerned.  I'm also confused by the "Map method" statement in the second line.  Does that refer to the inherited methods from java.util.Map, or something else?