# ModelMap vs Model in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am comparing [ModelMap](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ui/ModelMap.html) and [Model](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ui/Model.html) from Spring MVC. Apart from obvious difference that first is a class and second an interface **is there any difference that make a usage of one or another preferable in different situations?**

Primarily they are used for same purpose (as from [spring MVC](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) documentation):

> java.util.Map / org.springframework.ui.Model /
>   org.springframework.ui.ModelMap for enriching the implicit model that
>   is exposed to the web view.

Only I have found out there it that `ModelMap` is enhanced `Map`, however difference to `Model` is still unclear.

Can I conclude from ModelMap javadoc that 'Model' is preferred for java 5?

> Check out the Model interface for a Java-5-based interface variant
>   that serves the same purpose.

However it does not seem that `ModelMap` would be deprecated or something. But why does `ModelMap` does not implement `Model`?

Comment: `ExtendedModelMap` is extending `ModelMap` and implementing `ModelMap`. When using the `Model` you can chain method calls as most methods return `Model` with a `Map` or `ModelMap` this isn't the case.

Comment: thanks for `ExtendedModelMap`. AFAIK you can chain calls with `ModelMap` as well (in difference to `Map` that I have already noticed).

Comment: Ah yes you are right. `ModelMap` also predates the `Model` interface. For that interface there are basically 2 implementations, the `ExtendedModelMap` and the `RedirectAttributesModelMap` (there is also the `BindingAwareModelMap` which is an extension the the `ExtendedModelMap`). For the usage in the request mapping methods it doesn't really matter which one to use, although I would probably suggest to use the `Model` interface instead one of the implementations. But that is highly opinionated :).

Comment: answer for a similar question can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18486660/what-are-the-differences-between-model-modelmap-and-modelandview

Answer (score -1):

`Model` - Java-5-specific interface that defines a holder for model attributes. Primarily designed for adding attributes to the model. Allows for accessing the overall model as a java.util.Map.

Simply put, the model can supply attributes used for rendering views.

---

`ModelMap` -  ModelMap class is basically a LinkedHashMap. It add some methods for convenience. Just like the **Model** interface above, **ModelMap** is also used to pass values to render a view.

The advantage of ModelMap is it gives us the ability to pass a collection of values and treat these values as if they were within a Map:

```
@GetMapping("/printViewPage")
public String passParametersWithModelMap(ModelMap map) {
    map.addAttribute("welcomeMessage", "welcome");
    map.addAttribute("message", "Baeldung");
    return "viewPage";
}
```

reference;

- https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ui/Model.html
- https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ui/ModelMap.html

Comment: Hi, 
The sample code provided does not seem to demonstrate the ability "to pass a collection of values" .  

When i look at the API for Model (not ModelMap), i notice that Model also provide api called add addAllAttributes, which also allow "to pass a collection of values". 

So ultimately, I still don't see the difference between modelMap and Model.