# Need help in understanding Model and ModelMap in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

I am confused about the usage of Model and ModelMap in the controller handlers.When to use Model and when ModelMap?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Model is an interface.ModelMap is a class.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer or visit this link it is easy to explain Model and ModelMap

[Model and ModelMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18486660/what-are-the-differences-between-model-modelmap-and-modelandview)

Comment: Thanks Sanjay.I know Model an interface and ModelMap is a class.But I want to know context in which these are used.I meant when do we go for Model and when ModelMap.