# What is the actual implementation of Model in Spring MVC

Tags: java, rest, model

A lot of people have answered that `Model` is an interface while `ModelView` is a class implementing `Map` interface.

1. My confusion is what actually implements interface `Model` then? (I am a beginner of *Spring MVC* so please be patient
   You can refer to this thread for code hint.
   [What are the differences between Model, ModelMap, and ModelAndView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18486660/what-are-the-differences-between-model-modelmap-and-modelandview)
2. More interestingly, I saw someone just use `Map<>` interface:

// When the path is routed to '/new' below method to be called and view //returned is newPokemon

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value ="/new")

    public String newPokemonForm(Map<String, Object> model) {
    Pokemon Pokemon = new Pokemon();
    model.put("pokemon", Pokemon);
    return "newPokemon";
}
```

So I am thinking for this model **parameter**, `Map<>` should be declared type while modelmap is the actual type?
Can anyone clarify with me?
Thanks a lot

----------------------------------Update----------------------------

For the first question, actually it is easy to check in Intellij. Just open the source code package thanks to Elmar Brauch. I will present the picture:
[image: screenshot of finding the related source code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you configure your build tool to download sources, you can just open Spring's Model interface. The type hierarchy (you can open it in Eclipse) shows you, that the following classes implement Model interface:

- public class ConcurrentModel extends ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> implements Model
- public class ExtendedModelMap extends ModelMap implements Model

In both classes you can see that they extend some kind of Map-class, which implements in a super class the Map interface.

At runtime You can figure out, which type is used as implementation of Map interface.  Set a breakpoint and inspect in debug mode or do something like this:

```
@PostMapping
public void postMap(@RequestBody Map map) {
    System.out.println(map.getClass());
}
```

This prints for my with @RestController annotated class this type:
class java.util.LinkedHashMap

Comment: hello, Thanks. With your hint, I know how to find the source code. Before I only know how to find them via ctr+left click.

Comment: But since both classes implements the interface, do you know which one is the actual type just like the second question? Thx.

Comment: class org.springframework.validation.support.BindingAwareModelMap is my printed result for Map<String, Object>. I got confused and how does the container know which class to use since so many classes implement model interface